Vertical Circular Motion ($u$ minimum)
In vertical circular motion, when we consider motion of a pendulum bob, while finding minimum velocity to complete VCM, we take Tension=0 at highest point and velocity at highest point is not equal to zero. But in VCM of a rod, we take $v=0$ at highest point while finding $u$ minimum, as rod cannot slack.
But what does slacking have to do with speed at highest point?

For the vertical pendulum, the string will not be taut for speeds at the apex $v < v_c $ where $v_c$ is the minimum speed calculated by letting the tension approach zero. Therefore the bob will fall out of the loop before $v$ can reach zero. A rod cannot buckle like this, because a rigid rod introduces the constraint that the bob will move with a constant radius in the first place, e.g. not fall out of the loop. In this case, it must simply have enough energy to pass the top point.

But my question is why can't v be equal to zero at highest point in case of pendulum.What do you mean 'fall out of the loop before v can reach zero'? Why would it fall?

Have you ever tried to do a vertical loop slowly, with a yo-yo for instance? It will not complete the loop, but fall out of circular motion without completing the loop.

Yes, I get that it should be projected with a minimum velocity equal to √5gr, but what I'm not getting is why v at highest point of motion can't be = 0 as in case of a rod

Because the subsequent motion would be a vertical fall only affected by gravity.

That is per definition not "vertical circular motion".

And in case of a rod? Isn't gravity there too?

Can the bob at the end of a rigid rod (I assume rotating around a hinge at the origin) fall straight down?

Okay, thank you so much I get it now. Meaning Normal Reaction would be balancing it right?

Yes, otherwise we would not call the rod rigid :)

Just one last question, what propels the rod to complete Vertical Circular Motion if v becomes zero at highest point? If projected with minimum velocity?

If it was possible to give it a starting velocity so that it reaches exactly $v=0$ at the top, it would stay there, in an unstable equilibrium. In practice you almost alwahs either give it too much or too little starting speed, in which case it either falls back the way it came, or continues through the loop.

If we have mass $m$ on a string of length $R$, on Earth ($g$), then the potential energy vs standard pendulum angle is:
$$U(\theta) = mgR(1-\cos\theta) + C$$
where $C$ is a constant.
I want to pick $C$ so that:
$$U_{max}= U(\pi) = 2mgR + C = 0$$
or $C= -2mgR$:
The reason I picked that is so I can write the conserved total energy as:
$$E = T + U = \frac 1 2 m(R\dot\theta)^2 - mgR(1 + \cos\theta) $$
The kinetic energy then satisfies:
$$ T(\theta)  = E_{min} - U(\theta) $$
with
$$E_{min} = T_{min} = T(\pi)$$
the minimum kinetic energy for the thing to work.
At that point the mass is on a circular trajectory, which requires (at $\theta=\pi$):
$$ F_g + F_T = F_{centripetal}$$
setting the tension force $F_T=0$, which I assume is the minimum velocity:
$$ mg  = m\frac{v_{min}^2}R$$
or:
$$ v_{min} = \sqrt{gR}$$
so a minimum kinetic energy:
$$ T_{min} = \frac 1 2 mv_{min}^2 = \frac 1 2 mgR $$
which I then note that:
$$ T_{min} = \frac 1 4 \Delta U $$
where $\delta U$ is the available potential energy.
Now I'm getting Virial Theorem vibes, but I don't know where to go that right now.
On a pedagogical note: the formula for $U$ and $T$ were not required to assert that only gravity contributes to keeping the mass on a circle, I could have started their, but then I wouldn't have been able to express the minimum speed in terms of a fraction of available potential energy.
Another thing to do would be to Taylor expand the would-be ballistic trajectory around the peak, and ensure that it remains outside the circle: that is, that the string doesn't collapse. Or look at the radius of curvature of a trajectory:
$$ r_c = \frac{|\vec v|^3}{\vec v \times \dot{\vec v}} $$
That would be nice, but I don't have time to do that right now.

umm Half of the things you mentioned went over my head, I only have a basic understanding of all this (11th grade physics)

Ballistic trajectory means falling, so you have to ensure it's not falling, which requires gravity to provide the centripetal force at the apex, which sets the VCM, which I converted to energy--the top and bottom of the loop have a potential energy difference, and VCM corresponds to 1/4 of that.
